# what is arg0 of setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.valueOf(arg0))?

Tags: java, android, zooming, android-webview

I want to zoom the webview to any percentage with the function of

```
setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.valueOf(arg0)
```

But I do not know how to set the value of `arg0` correctly.

I tried to use `setInitialScale()` to set the zoom percentage, but it does not work for some web page.

Answer (score 0):

[`WebSettings.ZoomDensity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.ZoomDensity.html) is just an `enum` with the values `CLOSE`, `FAR`, and `MEDIUM`. So to answer your title question: `arg0` is one of the strings `"CLOSE"`, `"FAR"`, or `"MEDIUM"`. This would lead to:

```
setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.valueOf("CLOSE"));
```

But that could be stated more simply as:

```
setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
```

And if you used a static import statement such as:

```
import static android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity.*;
```

Then you could simply and elegantly do this:

```
setDefaultZoom(CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.ZoomDensity.html), `ZoomDensity` is an enum for setting the desired density.

So you can set it like so:

```java
setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);

setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
```

`valueOf()` is just a way to convert a string into an enum value:

```java
setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.valueOf("CLOSE"));

setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.valueOf("FAR"));

setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.valueOf("MEDIUM"));
```

Answer (score 0):

WebSettings.ZoomDensity is an enumeration and the valueOf(String) method is inherited from Enum<E>. The setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity) method should be called like:

```
setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
```

[Here is the documentation for the ZoomDensity enum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.ZoomDensity.html)